# How to avoid errors thrown by MVC validation before reaching fluent validation implementation C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

When a request to my MVC application is made it could not return the
    proper error , because the request can not reach the fluent
    validation flow , because the error is thrown before it by the
    default MVC validation. The MVC validation is the one which came
    with MVC project when it is created in the beggining. It checks if
    the model is valid and returns error before fluent validation. I
    read all relevant documentation regarding fluent validation , but I
    couldn’t found case where we can turn off MVC default validation 
    and use only fluent validation or some kind of implementation in the
    default MVC. May someone give me some articles or proper examples if
    he/she had faced the same issue ? All information will be really
    appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide you model and validation rules so I can test it, and see if some workaround is possible

Comment: The MVC validations are the default ones and the validations are the same as the provided in the fluent validation documentation which is given here in the above comment of Alexander. My app is .net core app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [disable Automatic Model State Validation in ASP.NET Core](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/disable-automatic-model-state-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-1/).

Answer (score 3):

Fluent validation [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/mvc5#known-limitations) about MVC 5 states

> **Known Limitations**
>
> MVC 5 performs validation in two passes. First it tries to convert the input values from the request into the types declared in your model, and then it performs model-level validation using FluentValidation. If you have non-nullable types in your model (such as int or DateTime) and there are no values submitted in the request, model-level validations will be skipped, and only the type conversion errors will be returned.
>
> This is a limitation of MVC 5’s validation infrastructure, and there is no way to disable this behaviour. If you want all validation failures to be returned in one go, you must ensure that any value types are marked as nullable in your model (you can still enforce non-nullability with a NotNull or NotEmpty rule as necessary, but the underlying type must allow nulls). This only applies to MVC5 and WebApi 2. ASP.NET Core does not suffer from this issue as the validation infrastructure has been improved.

Comment: Yes, I read this yesterday. I saw that this behavior cannot be switched off. My app is .net core app. Where can I see this improvement and how it works?